# PDF JavaScript support in Mac OS safari browser

Tags: macos, pdf, browser, safari, adobe

This may not the the place to ask this question, but I've done a lot of searching and couldn't find any clear answer.

I have a PDF built with Adobe Acrobat DC with a lot of JavaScript (mostly changing some field value based on other fields, of just simple validation). That PDF is served from a Web Application. In MacOS, the PDF JavaScript does not seem to work when the PDF is opened in Safari or in the default MacOS preview application, but works perfectly fine when opened with Adobe Reader or chrome. However, starting Safari v11, adobe reader safari plugin has been discontinued/not supported, therefore the PDF first opens in the Safari default PDF viewer(with wrong values, because JS is not triggered I think) and only from there it can be opened in Adobe Reader, this is very bad UX.

I just wanted to make sure if PDF JavaScript is indeed not supported in Safari or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by [`object-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/object-src) in [`CSP`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).
If your pdf is self-hosted, you can set `object-src: [ self ]`.